# How to add Table data from cs file to aspx.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know how I could connect these two files to work.

output.cs file

```
public static void PrintGrid(Grid grid)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= grid.GetHeight(); j++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i <= grid.GetWidth(); i++)
        {

            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = grid.Get(i, j);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

        }
        Table1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Form1.aspx.cs file

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //other code
    InOut.PrintGrid(grid);
}
```

I tested it and wrote it in Button1_Click class ant it works fine, but in some way I need to write this fragment in another cs file and print this table in aspx.

Comment: add namespace of PrintGrid method by `using` to `Form1.aspx.cs`

Comment: How can that posted code work, where is Table1 defined? I don't see it???

Answer (score 0):

Well, your static class does NOT have Table1 defined.

So, say this:

```
public static class GridOutPut
{
    public static void PrintGrid(GridView grid, DataTable MyTable)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= grid.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int i = 0; i <= grid.Columns.Count; i++)
            {

                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = grid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

            }
            MyTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

(and don't use "output", as that is far to common of a name - and output used for all kind of things!!).

So, now your code say is like this:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // dt.Columns.Add() or whatever.

        GridOutPut.PrintGrid(GridView1, dt);
```

So, pass the grid AND the table to that routine.

Of course the above is "air code", but it should suffice for the approach here.

So, you need to pass both the grid variable (instance), (I don't know what you using), and then the table